# How to change back button text in iPad in Swift UI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Working on iPhone, iPad and Mac OS app, which has login screen. I took login View in NavigationView, when I tap on back button the login view will slide as split view. Now I want to change back button text to Login text.

Any one have any idea how&where to change for this?

[image: backbutton text]

Comment: Why do you want to use navigation view without navigation bar ? BRW , try with toolbar item group.

Comment: There is signup, forgot password and other screen associated from login screen that is why I used navigation view and Hide navigation bar at first.

Comment: You could use a @state var isSignup to show either login/signup screen or navigation view with part of app once logged

Comment: That's ok. But my point is how I can change back button.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom view for the button

```
struct BackButton: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    var foregroundColor: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()}) {
            HStack {
                
                Image(systemName: Image.arrowLeft)
                    .foregroundColor(foregroundColor)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                Text("the text you need")
                    .foregroundColor(foregroundColor)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

after you can use it's some views:

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                    ScrollView {
                     
                    }.navigationBarItems(leading: BackButton(presentationMode: _presentationMode, foregroundColor: .whiteTextColor))
                }
        }
```

Also before you need delete default button, you can use it inside NavigationLink()

```
NavigationLink(destination: SomeView()
                            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                            .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
                            .navigationBarHidden(true),
                           isActive: self.$isNext,
                           label: { EmptyView() })
```

Result:
[image]